# Change variable name in a loop

Tags: less, mixins, less-mixins

I need the variable `name` to change to `trees`, `balloons` etc in a loop in order to obtain

```
.trees{ color:1;}
.balloons { color:2;}
```

but I obtain instead:

```
.trees{color:2}  
.name{color:1}
```

Tried this mixin but is not working, what I'm doing wrong?

```
@name:name;
.name(@index) when (@index = 2) {@name: balloons;}
.name(@index) when (@index = 1) {@name: trees;}
.name(@index) when (@index > 0) {
.@{name}{ color:@index; }
  .name(@index - 1)
}
.name(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdZdZb), you have to use [list](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions) of desired names and you can get any element of the list by it index:

```
@item: extract(@names, @index);
```

Comment: Nice and best solution to the problem :)

Comment: Though it would be handy to include the whole snippet to the answer too (after all it's just [a few lines of code](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/14a2e640cf20897e27f8)).